# GET and POST request not working for a ip-address (Internal server error)

Tags: php, ajax, request, internal-server-error

I am working on an application which I have to migrate to another server i.e. Amazon.Now I created an EC2 instance,configured it and installed the application.All is fine but my ajax requests are giving me an `internal server error 501` message.

I have the same application running on a different domain(I am migrating it to **Amazon**) and it works fine.On amazon I have an ip-address at which the application runs and it does not have a domain name.(i.e **X.X.X.X/home.php**). I cross checked the paths by trying both **absolute and relative** urls,but I still get the same error,even though the file is present.
Also,I tried changing the permissions from **644 to 755**,but no result.

 I would like some inputs over if this is happening because **I don't have a domain name yet for the IP**(It works fine on my old server which is a godaddy one and has a domain name pointed to it)?

Comment: Does `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` work?

Comment: yes!Even other files are visible...only my requests fail!specifically made through ajax jquery!

Comment: Have you checked your logs to see what's causing the 501 ?

Comment: I checked the ec2 logs but I didn't find any entry!i gues I need to go to the server logs on my root!I am checking them and revert once done.thanks @tlenss

Comment: `Premature end of script headers` This is what the logs say!Tried removing the htacess but didn't help

Comment: @tlenss @Amal Murali : This is what I get in the error logs now `Fatal error: Class 'DOMDocument' not found`.I checked for the dom extension and its available as I can't find `--disable-dom`

Comment: Its not!!How can I install it? Its on amazon server an EC2 instance.I hope I don't have to recompile!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP 5 should come with dom enabled by default. Which you can check by inspecting the php info output.

```
dom

DOM/XML enabled
DOM/XML API Version 20031129
libxml Version  2.7.8
HTML Support    enabled
XPath Support   enabled
XPointer Support    enabled
Schema Support  enabled
RelaxNG Support enabled
```

If you are using PHP 5 and for some reason dom is not available. Check for a package in your repositories called **php5-xml**

Comment: I am using PHP 5.3 but for some reason it was not enabled or installed on the LAMP stack.I did it and its working now!Actually I didn't face such issues with my previous installations and hence took time to figure out. Thank you for the help.